# How to schedule multiple jobs from multiple properties files in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, scheduled-tasks

I have a folder with multiple properties files each file corresponding to a data type, like
example1.properties
example2.properties
example3.properties
I would like to iterate over this folder and schedule some jobs.

So far, i have managed to schedule a single instance for one data type (example1).
I use a single property file `application.properties` in which i have `app.cron.rule=0 * * * * *` with some other properties specific to `example1`

```
    @Scheduled(cron ="${app.cron.rule}")
    public void doSomething() {
        doSomething("example1"); // uses properties values in example1.properties to process some data
    }
```

I would like to loop over the files of the folder and create a cron for every file.
I cannot define N cron in my application because the number of crons is dynamic, and is depending on the amount of properties files.

If you have another way to achieve that than using multiple properties file, or if you a clue to make this work i would be glad to hear it out.

I hope this is not a duplicate, but i haven't found any.

**Update**

Here is some more details of my code :

I have a class :

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:observation.properties")
public class MyService {
    
    @Value("${app.data.location}")
    private String dataLocation;

    @Value("${app.data.type}")
    private String dataType;

    // other attributes loaded from application.properties

    public void doSomething() {
        // use dataLocation and data type to process some data. 
    }
}
```

I have another class :

```
public class MyScheduler {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Scheduled(cron ="${app.cron.rule}")
    public void doSomething() {
        myService.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Currently i only have a properties file :
*application.properties*

```
app.cron.rule=0 * * * * *
app.data.location=/location/number/1
app.data.type=type1
```

I would like to have multiple properties file containing different values for `app.cron.rule`, `app.data.location`, `app.data.type` (type1.properties, type2.properties, etc...) and to schedule a job for every file, ie :

```
public class MyScheduler {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    for(file in folder) {
        @Scheduled(cron ="${app.cron.rule}")
        public void doSomething() {
            myService.doSomething(); // the attributes in myService should change acording 
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot do it that way, but it represents what i'm trying to do.

Comment: _because the number of crons is dynamic, and is depending on the amount of properties files..._  Since property files are being added, how is it dynamic?  Can you expand the code example with more details?

Comment: I tried to expand the code in the question, updated it so it's more detailed. Hope it helps. thanks for your time :)

Comment: Instead of multiple property files, consider defining of list of objects within a single property file.  Each object would have the cron and the data needed for `MyService`.  The schedule would need to be programmatically set, and pass the config to myService.

Comment: Let say i use a single property file. Now i want to add an object to the list, it means i have to rewrite my app to take it into account and to schedule it. 
There is no way to schedule it without rewriting any code, just by changing the application.properties ? 
Thanks

Comment: No - the object is the configuration used to schedule `MyService` and whatever properties it needs to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create endpoints from which I can view/create/add/remove jobs, and persist a list of running jobs instead of doing it with files which the server directly reads. If you really want to do it with files in `/foo/bar`, one way would be to make the files in the form of:

```
// job0.txt
app.job.id=0
app.cron.rule=0 * * * * *
app.data.location=/location/number/1
app.data.type=type1

// job1.txt
app.job.id=1
app.cron.rule=0 1 * * * *
app.data.location=/location/whatever/number/1
app.data.type=foo
...
```

Keep a local cache of already running jobs using the `app.job.id` property of every file. Start a job, which runs let's say every minute, in your application that reads all files from `/foo/bar` and checks if the jobs with the ids in your cache still exist, if not we will need to cancel them, and if there are any jobs with a new id we will create a new job for it. We can use [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) for this purpose, for usage examples see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler. After we have a `taskScheduler` a sketch of a simple implementation might be:

```
  private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
  
  private List<RunningTask> runningTasks = new ArrayList(); 
  
  private void handleFiles() {
    // get all actions based on the files and 
    // currently present RunningTask instances in runningTasks
    List<Action> actionList = getActions();  
    
    for (Action action : actionList) {
        if (action.type == EAction.START) {
            runningTasks.add(
                new RunningTask(
                    // taskHandle to enable cancelling tasks
                    taskScheduler.schedule(taskWorker(action.getData()), action.getCron()),
                    // taskId so we are able to identify which tasks are removed
                    action.getTaskId()
                )
            );
        }
        else if (action.type == EAction.STOP) {
            cancelTask(action.getTaskId());
        }
        ...
        // handle other possible action types like update...
    }
  }
```